# Please help me with this PHP

Tags: php, foreach, range

I'm trying to create a simple multiplication table using this code:

```
foreach(range(1,5) as $a){
    foreach(range(1,5) as $b){
        echo $b*=$a, " ";
    }
    echo $a, "<br />";
}
```

but I got a little problem in the output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 1
2 4 6 8 10 2
3 6 9 12 15 3
4 8 12 16 20 4
5 10 15 20 25 5
```

you can probably see what. I'm just learning php and am really out of idea.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: That output is exactly what it should be. Whats your expected output?

Comment: without the repeating 1,2,3,4,5 at the end of the columns/rows.

Comment: `printf("[%3s]", $b*=$a)` instead of `echo $b*=$a, " ";` and with `echo "<br />";` without `$a` in?

Comment: Ok then simply remove `echo $a, "<br />";` and do `echo "<br />";`

Comment: foreach(range(1,5) as $a){
    foreach(range(1,5) as $b){
        echo $b*$a . " ";
    }
    echo "<br />";
}

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(range(1,5) as $a){
    foreach(range(1,5) as $b){
        echo $b*=$a, " ";
    }
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Just remove the `$a echo` ;)

Comment: I was just about to post exactly this :')

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
echo $a, "<br />";
```

with

```
 echo "<br>";
```